# C++ How can I make my class private and still have access?

Tags: c++, private, public

Good day sir!,
I'm just learning C++ and I want to modify my current program (a simple calculator that lets the user choose the operation then ask him to input 2 numbers to be computed.) and make the class 'Math' private but still make the program work.

My code is as follows, any help would be appreciated :) thanks in advance!:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    class Math{
        public:
            int addition(int x, int y){
            int sum = x + y;
            return sum;
    }

            int subtraction(int x, int y){
            int difference = x - y;
            return difference;
    }

            int multiplication(int x, int y){
            int product = x * y;
            return product;
    }

            float division(float x, float y){
            float quotient = x / y;
            return quotient;
    }
    };

    int main()
    {
        Math mathObject;
        int n,a,b;
        cout << "\t[1] Addition\n\t[2] Subtraction\n\t[3] Multiplication\n\t[4] Division\n\nChoose Operation number: ";
        cin >> n;
        cout << "\n\nInput first number: "; cin >> a; cout << "\nInput second number: "; cin >> b;

        if(n==1){
            cout << "\n\nThe answer is " << mathObject.Addition(a,b) << endl;
        }

        if(n==2){
            cout << "\n\nThe answer is " << mathObject.subtraction(a,b) << endl;
        }

        if(n==3){
            cout << "\n\nThe answer is " << mathObject.multiplication(a,b) << endl;
        }
        if(n==4){
            cout << "\n\nThe answer is " << mathObject.division(a,b) << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Make the class private to what?  C++ doesn't have a concept of classes being private within namespaces or binary modules like C# does.  You can effectively make it private within the compilation unit by putting it an anonymous namespace.

Comment: The methods in your main function don't match the ones you defined in the class :L

Comment: How can I have my cake and eat it to? Nobody knows... Hehe, but seriously, the way your program is right now, `Math` is already confined to the .cpp file where you've defined it. So it is somewhat private. If you wanted to make it "public", then you would have to put a class declaration in a header file and the definition in a .cpp file. Quite different from C#, Java and others where class declaration and definition are in the same place.

Answer (score 2):

About the most "private" you could make your class is to put it into an [anonymous namespace](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/topic/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/unnamed_namespaces.htm).

```
namespace {

class Math{
// ...
};

} // end anon namespace
```

This allows anything in the same translation unit to access the items in the anonymous namespace, but the symbols in that namespace aren't available to other translation units (i.e. source files) for linking.